# Como criar uma sequência em varchar no banco de dados Postgres?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte tabela no banco de dados *Postgres*:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  userid character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  firstname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  balance double precision NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
```

Seria possível criar uma sequencia do tipo auto incremento mas que fosse do tipo `VARCHAR`?

Pois tenho um objeto da regra de negócios que precisa de um tipo `String`.

Conheço o procedimento para criar uma sequência com o tipo `serial`:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  userid serial NOT NULL,
  ...
  ...
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
```

Mas como disse antes, preciso de um tipo `VARCHAR`, porque os valores que serão inseridos como chave primaria vão possuir esta forma:

```
id001  
id002  
id003
```

Answer (score 5):

Com `varchar` você terá que criar uma `tigger` e incrementar seu campo.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_transaction_id() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.userid  :=  'id' || nextval('seq_name');
  RETURN NEW;
END; 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Sendo que `seq_name` é o nome do seu generator. (Caso não exista você deve criá-lo)

Criar generator: `CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name START 1;`

E a trigger na tabela para executar a function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inc_id
  AFTER INSERT
  ON customer
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_transaction_id();
```

Comment: @EduardoBrito Isso eu sei!! Mas eu quero criar um valor do tipo varchar que seja alto incremento!!

Comment: Aguarde que vou alterar minha resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: @EduardoBrito Pensei ainda em usar um procedimento  para fazer isso mas descartei a  ideia, entretanto, com uma tigger  , como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Alterei a resposta, de uma olhada se pode te ajudar.

Comment: Caso Resolva seu problema e quiser é claro me dar a melhor resposta eu agradeço.

Comment: @EduardoBrito Esse generator seq_name eu devo criar de que forma?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29373/discussion-between-pena-pintada-and-eduardo-binotto).

Comment: CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name START 1;